# Is it possible to Enumerate possible containernames for a XNA storage container?

Tags: c#, xna, storage, xbox360

As the title says really.

I want to enable sharing user generated content easily by allowing users to save levels in seperate containers, so that they can transfer them to USB -> another xbox, rather than transfering them all + config files etc.

Ideally i want them to be able to choose the name of the container so that many 'exported' levels can exist on the same storage device. Then when they plug in the USB device the game searches for any container on the storage device. Hence the need to enumnerate containers (containernames).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible unfortunately.